# Can you tell someone has seen combat by looking at their face?

Tags: physiology

There is a common claim that, by looking into the face or eyes of a person, you can see that they have seen combat, or other traumatic events. It is particularly mentioned in movies, songs and poems.

Examples:

- Movie: [The Objective](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0962711/) - an old man tells a soldier he can see the desert in his eyes.
- Poetry: [A Soldier's Eyes](http://iwvpa.net/hutchersonj/a-soldie-en.php) by Johnny Hutcherson
- Essay: [The Eyes Of A Soldier](http://www.darkcanyon.net/The%20Eyes%20Of%20A%20Soldier.htm) by William Douglas Roser, I.

Are there any studies that show if you can indeed see in one's eyes his (traumatic) experiences. If so, is it general trauma, or is it possible you can detect "the desert", "the combat", "killing", etc... in the eyes or face?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users)! This question treads firmly into the [Are movie claims notable?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/random-claims-from-fantasy-stories-and-movies) territory. What do people think? Is this a claim that the movie producers expect you to believe, or just a fictional (and cliched) way of establishing a character's motivation, like $$$ symbols appearing in a cartoon character's eyes?

Comment: Well I hear that claim a lot from almost any kind of proffessiols whose job is difficult or dangerous. I think peoples do believe that.

Comment: Excellent. That should help. If you hear it a lot, there shouldn't be much trouble finding a non-fictional example on the web.

Comment: Well theres: http://www.vietmemories.com/hutch2.htm and it took 1 minute. Not the best ref I guess.

Comment: Some [anecdotal data](http://www.lostateminor.com/2012/11/08/portraits-of-soldiers-before-during-and-after-deployment-to-afghanistan/), so you can see for yourself.